# Which one of these is actual Java String Constructor definition for String(String )

Tags: java, string, constructor

I am able to find these two definitions for String constructor with one String argument:

```
public String(String original) {
        int size = original.count;
        char[] originalValue = original.value;
        char[] v;
        if (originalValue.length > size) {
            // The array representing the String is bigger than the new
            // String itself.  Perhaps this constructor is being called
            // in order to trim the baggage, so make a copy of the array.
            int off = original.offset;
            v = Arrays.copyOfRange(originalValue, off, off+size);
        } else {
            // The array representing the String is the same
            // size as the String, so no point in making a copy.
            v = originalValue;
        }
        this.offset = 0;
        this.count = size;
        this.value = v;
    }
```

and

```
  public String(String original) {
        this.value = original.value;
        this.hash = original.hash;
    }
```

Not sure which one is original implementation.

Also do we have any scenario where second implementation may fail?

Comment: Your SDK should include the sources. You could look there. For OpenJDK you can search [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/String.java?av=f).

Comment: FYI I checked the definition of my SDK and it shows the second definition.

Comment: The change was introduced in java 1.7.0_06: http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/